# Pattern to iterate Request Params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

My view is not a strongly typed view and I need to iterate through Request Params in the controller action to determine the values posted.

Is there a better way to iterate through the nameValueCollection AllKeys?

I am currently looping through the Request Params and setting values appropriately.

```
 foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
 { 
     if (key.Equals("CustomerId"))
        queryObject.CustomerId = Request.Params[key];
     else if (key.Equals("OrderId"))
       queryObject.OrderId= Request.Params[key];
     //and so on
 }
```

I see a considerable amount of repetition in this code. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why are you not doing this in your controller? I see `queryObject` which worries me that you are going to do a DB query from your view. That is not MVC. You should take advantage of the model binding on action parameters to do all this in the controller action.

Comment: You should mark @Arce Brito's answer as correct. It does precisely what the question asked. Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Because the **NameValueCollection** does not provide a **Search method** and simply by clarify your code, you could do the following:

```
 foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
 { 
      queryObject.CustomerId = key.Equals("CustomerId") ? Request.Params[key] : queryObject.CustomerId;
      queryObject.OrderId = key.Equals("OrderId") ? Request.Params[key] : queryObject.OrderId;
     //and so on ...
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this?

```
queryObject.CustomerId = Request.Params["CustomerId"];
queryObject.OrderId = Request.Params["OrderId"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you not use reflection to getProperties from your query object, then read through them to get the corresponding items from the request.params?

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like C# has an equivalent of a Java `Map`:

[Java Map equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687942/java-map-equivalent-in-c)

If nothing else works, I'd recommend building a `Dictionary` of key-value pairs, then reading the values out of the `Dictionary` into the class object.